# Solr: Indexing nested Documents via DIH

Tags: indexing, solr, lucene, dih

I want to index my document from **MySql** to **Solr** via **DIH**. I have a table structure like this

- Table User

  <kbd><kbd>id

  <kbd>1</kbd>

  <kbd>2</kbd>

  <kbd>3</kbd></kbd>

  <kbd>name

  <kbd>Jay</kbd>

  <kbd>Chakra</kbd>

  <kbd>Rabbit</kbd></kbd></kbd>
- Address

  <kbd><kbd>id

  <kbd>1</kbd>

  <kbd>2</kbd>

  <kbd>3</kbd></kbd>

  <kbd>number 

  <kbd>1111111111</kbd>

  <kbd>2222222222</kbd>

  <kbd>3333333333</kbd></kbd>

  <kbd>email 

  <kbd>test@email.com</kbd>

  <kbd>test123@test.co</kbd>

  <kbd>unique@email.com</kbd></kbd></kbd>

and other associations.

I want to index this in a nested document structure but unable to find any resource via which it can be done using DIH.

**Resources refered:**

- http://yonik.com/solr-nested-objects/
- https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/solr/Uploading+Data+with+Index+Handlers

Please suggest a way to index it through **DIH**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This feature has been implemented by [SOLR-5147](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SOLR-5147) and should be available for Solr 5.1+

Here is a sample configuration taken from the original Jira ticket.

```
<dataConfig>
  <dataSource type="JdbcDataSource" />
  <document>
    <entity name="PARENT" query="select * from PARENT">
      <field column="id" />
      <field column="desc" />
      <field column="type_s" />
      <entity child="true" name="CHILD" query="select * from CHILD where parent_id='${PARENT.id}'">
        <field column="id" />
        <field column="desc" />
        <field column="type_s" />
      </entity>
    </entity>
  </document>
</dataConfig>
```

note the ***child="true"*** is required for child entities.

Comment: This a config set for solr-data-config.xml

I am unable to write the corresponding schema. Can you post the corrosponding Schema?

Comment: There wasn't a requirement for the schema to index nested documents. More details and walk through can be found from yonik's post:  http://yonik.com/solr-nested-objects/